# Backup in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, backup

I have lots of site collection in SharePoint 2010 enterprise. Is there a way to do a backup if server is crashing, both website and database at the same time? If yes how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved through Central Administration. Go to Central Administration > Backuo and Restore and chose Configure backup setting:

[image]

It'll take you to the next screen where you specify where you want to store your backup:

[image]

## [Use Central Administration to back up a site collection in SharePoint Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748617%28v=office.14%29.aspx#section2)

If you only want to backup a single site collection, you can go from the start page of Central Administration navigating to Perform a site collection backup from in the section Backup and Restore:

[image]

> To back up a site collection by using Central Administration
>
> 1. Verify that the user account performing this procedure is a member of the Farm Administrators group. Additionally, verify that the Windows SharePoint Services Timer V4 service has Full Control permissions on the backup folder.
> 2. In Central Administration, on the Home page, in the Backup and Restore section, click Perform a site collection backup.
> 3. On the Site collection backup page, select the site collection from the Site Collection list.
> 4. Type the local path of the backup file in the Filename box. **Note**: If you want to reuse a file, select the **Overwrite existing file** check box.
> 5. Click Start Backup.
> 6. You can view the general status of all backup jobs at the top of the Granular Backup Job Status page in the Readiness section. You can view the status for the current backup job in the lower part of the page in the Site Collection Backup section. The status page updates every 30 seconds automatically. You can manually update the status details by clicking Refresh. Backup and recovery are Timer service jobs. Therefore, it may take several seconds for the backup to start.

Reference: [Use Central Administration to back up a site collection in SharePoint Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748617%28v=office.14%29.aspx#section2)